# PlotMarkers problem in ErrorListPlot, Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0, fixed in 10.1**

---

I recently upgraded to Mathematica 10, very excited about the multiple undo function of course.

However I very quickly noticed that if I specify a setting for `PlotMarkers` in the `ErrorListPlot` function, the error bars disappear. Even just setting `PlotMarkers->Automatic` makes the error bars disappear. This was not a problem in Mathematica 9, but appears to be a new 'feature'. Has anyone else noticed this since upgrading, and are there any possible fixes?

Comment: This works on OSX 10.9.4 when you add Joined -> True. Without it I see the same behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: Reproduced in my V10 under Win 7, 64 bit by using this code: Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]; ErrorListPlot[
 Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]

Comment: Thanks, Matariki. That brings the error bars back for me as well, but makes the plot exceptionally ugly. Hopefully there is another fix somewhere.

Comment: I'm still seeing this exact error in 10.0.2 on Mac OS X (10.10.2 Yosemite). The `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` workaround doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: @Ian I converted your answer to a comment.  If you wish to address this further please [post a new question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this is *not* fixed in 10.0.2 under OSX?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For me (v10.0.2 OSX10.9.5) : when the only option set is `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` the error bars disappear. If I add the option `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` OR if I add `Joined->True` the error bars come back. Do you get error bars on WindowsOS when `Joined->False` ?

Comment: @SquareOne Good catch.  With `Joined->False` the error bars disappear again.  I am removing the "fixed in ..." header.

Comment: NB: the workaround `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` has to go before the `PlotMarkers` option for this to work (for me, anyway).

Comment: For me the bug is there in "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)". If I specify any option for PlotMarkers the error bars disappear. The work around also does not help.

Answer (score 14):

I heard from technical support. The problem should be fixed in an upcoming release, but for now there is a temporary fix by inserting `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` into the `ErrorListPlot` options.

Comment: It's still there in 10.0.1, alas.

Answer (score 4):

> Even just setting PlotMarkers->Automatic makes the error bars
>   disappear

Fixed in 10.0.2. windows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{2, 2}, ErrorBar[0.1]}, {{3, 4}, 
   ErrorBar[0.3]}, {{4, 6}, ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{5, 7}, 
   ErrorBar[0.8]}, {{6, 10}, ErrorBar[0.5]}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{2, 2}, ErrorBar[0.1]}, {{3, 4}, 
   ErrorBar[0.3]}, {{4, 6}, ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{5, 7}, 
   ErrorBar[0.8]}, {{6, 10}, ErrorBar[0.5]}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

To answer comment below

> With Joined -> False the error bars disappear again.

This last part has now been fixed in **10.1** (windows). The bars remain when `Joined->False` is added

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: With `Joined -> False` the error bars disappear again.  This is not entirely fixed therefore.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  fyi, the `Joined->False`  is now fixed in 10.1, updated

Comment: Has there been a regression in 11.2.0? I run your last line (`ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{2, 2}, 
   ErrorBar[0.1]}, {{3, 4}, ErrorBar[0.3]}, {{4, 6}, 
   ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{5, 7}, ErrorBar[0.8]}, {{6, 10}, ErrorBar[0.5]}},
  Joined -> False, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`) and I get no error bars. I am running 11.2.0 on linux.

Comment: Same for me, no error bars in 11.2.0, not even using the `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` trick...