# ErrorListLogLogPlot and PlotMarkers

Tags: plotting

I recently upgraded to Mathematica 10.2.0.0 for Linux (32-bit).  In the past I have used the ErrorBarLogPlots package to put error bars on logarithmic plots of lists.  When I make a simple ErrorListLogLogPlot, everything seems reasonable:

```
ErrorListLogLogPlot[Table[{{kk, 2*kk}, ErrorBar[kk]}, {kk, 1, 5}], PlotRange -> {{0.5, 6}, {0.5, 20}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

produces:

[image]

When PlotMarkers are added,

```
ErrorListLogLogPlot[Table[{{kk, 2*kk}, ErrorBar[kk]}, {kk, 1, 5}], PlotRange -> {{0.5, 6}, {0.5, 20}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

the error bars disappear:

[image]

When Joined is True, the error bars return,

```
ErrorListLogLogPlot[Table[{{kk, 2*kk}, ErrorBar[kk]}, {kk, 1, 5}], PlotRange -> {{0.5, 6}, {0.5, 20}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reference for the package is in [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49123/245).

Comment: It seems to be the same problem that in [PlotMarkers problem in ErrorListPlot, Mathematica 10](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56132/plotmarkers-problem-in-errorlistplot-mathematica-10) but this has been fixed in 10.1 as it belongs to the standard packages, contrary to the `ErrorBarLogPlots` package ... Look at the comments in that post, there seem to be a workaround using `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False} ` which "has to go before the PlotMarkers option for this to work" according to the user evanb.  Maybe it will work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Addition of `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` solves the problem:

```
Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"]

ErrorListLogLogPlot[Table[{{kk + i/3, 2 kk}, ErrorBar[kk]}, {i, 1, 3}, {kk, 1, 5}], 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {1, 20}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I am running Mathematica 10.4.0. When I run all your example code I get the following **error: Get::noopen: Cannot open ErrorBarLogPlots`. >> Needs::nocont: Context ErrorBarLogPlots` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should download the package [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6747/) and install it.