# ListLogLogPlot with ErrorBars

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following data consisting of x, y pairs and errors of y:

```
dataWithError = {{0.0333333, 0.0000122672, 0.00000173485}, {0.05, 0.0000371462, 
                  0.00000448037}, {0.0666667, 0.0000697768, 0.00000748151}, 
                 {0.0833333, 0.000108625, 0.000010837}, {0.1, 0.000147595,
                  0.0000136051}, {0.116667, 0.000186599, 0.0000161483}, 
                 {0.133333, 0.000221451, 0.0000179078}, {0.15, 0.000253062, 0.0000192494}};
```

I can plot the data with error bars with:

```
ErrorListPlot[dataWithError, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The result is:

[image]

I need a `ListLogLogPlot` with error bars (both axes have to be logarithmic). How can that be done?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91560/errorlistloglogplot-and-plotmarkers?rq=1)

Comment: maybe this: [Asymmetric X and Y error bars on ListLogPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42144/5478)

Comment: @Kuba: this helps a lot ... thanks for the link

Comment: @BlacKow: that is what I was looking for, but I am surprised that `ErrorListLogLogPlot` has to be imported and is not included in MMA 10.4, or I am missing some information ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always perform coordinate transformation yourself. There is nothing so special about `LogLogPlot`. You have to apply `Log` to your points and plot it with regular `ErrorListPlot`. Keep in mind that your error bar won't be symmetric in log-log coordinates. After that you have to draw ticks according to your new scale.

This can be overkill for log-log case, but it gives you generic algorithm how to torture your axes any way you want.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

plotrange={Floor@Log10@Min[#],Ceiling@Log10@Max[#]}&@dataWithError[[All,#]]&/@{1,2};
logData={{Log10[#[[1]]],Log10[#[[2]]]},ErrorBar[Log10[1+0.5#]&/@{-#[[3]]/#[[2]],#[[3]]/#[[2]]} ] }&/@dataWithError;
xticks = {#,Superscript[10,#]}&/@Range[#1,#2,1]&@@plotrange[[1]];
yticks = {#,Superscript[10,#]}&/@Range[#1,#2,1]&@@plotrange[[2]];
{xt,yt}=#~Join~({#,""}&/@Flatten[(#[[1]]+Log10[{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}])&/@#])&/@{xticks,yticks};

 ErrorListPlot[logData, Joined -> True, PlotRange->plotrange,FrameTicks->{{yt,None},{xt,None}},Frame->True,Axes->False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica 12, you can use the new [Around](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) function inside `ListLogLogPlot`. No need for `ErrorBarPlots` any more.

```
toPlot = Map[({#[[1]], Around[#[[2]], #[[3]]]}) &, dataWithError];
ListLogLogPlot[toPlot, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]