# Using ErrorBars with ListLogPlot in Mathematica 11

Tags: warning-messages, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to insert error bars in a plot with a log scaled y-axis with

```
datam3err = {{0., 3570., 3570., 59.7495, 59.7495, 0., 0.}, {5.9, 970., 3159., 31.1448, 56.205, -1.30302, -0.12231}, {11.8, 300., 2620., 7.74597, 51.1859, -2.47654, -0.309391}, {17.7, 107., 2220., 4.62601, 21.0713, -3.50749, -0.475058}, {23.6, 42., 1876., 2.89828, 19.3701, -4.44265, -0.643424}, {29.5, 0., 1525., 0., 17.4642, "", ""}}
ErrorListLogPlot[{{#1, #3}, ErrorBarPlots`ErrorBar @@ {#6, #7}} & @@@ 
  datam3err]
```

I found several old questions trying to do the same thing (for example this one: [Plotting Error Bars on a Log Scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/plotting-error-bars-on-a-log-scale)), but the linked extra package in the answers does not work on Mathematica 11, the installation fails all the time. I assume this happens since it was initially written for Mathematica 6?

So how can I solve this problem with Mathematica 11?

Comment: Can you post some of your data?

Comment: Of course! 

datam3err = {{0., 3570., 3570., 59.7495, 59.7495, 0., 0.}, {5.9, 970., 3159., 
  31.1448, 56.205, -1.30302, -0.12231}, {11.8, 300., 2620., 7.74597, 
  51.1859, -2.47654, -0.309391}, {17.7, 107., 2220., 4.62601, 
  21.0713, -3.50749, -0.475058}, {23.6, 42., 1876., 2.89828, 
  19.3701, -4.44265, -0.643424}, {29.5, 0., 1525., 0., 17.4642, "", 
  ""}}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListLogLogPlot with ErrorBars](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111686/listloglogplot-with-errorbars) (the answer to that question can easily be adapted to semi-log plots)

Comment: @LukasLang So the solution is to take the log of all data points and then manually change the scale?

Comment: @A.S. Essentially, yes - you can easily pack all of that into a function if you want though